# Using the verb 'have' instead of the verb 'eat'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I used to think that the verb **have** can only be used when we talk about meals, which [means](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/meal?q=meal)  an occasion when people sit down to eat food, especially breakfast, lunch, or dinner. But I see native speakers say:

> I eat breakfast.

I mean they use the verb **eat** for a meal like breakfast or dinner. So my questions are:

1. Is this common to say "I am eating breakfast, lunch or dinner"  for a meal time?
2. Can we use the word **have** with the word **eat** interchangeably?

For example when somebody phoned us while we are eating something (at anytime) and asks

> What are you doing?

Can we also say:

> I having some pizza now. I'll call you back.

Comment: Some people are uncomfortable with both *eat* and *drink* for things like soup, and *have* gives them a way to avoid saying either one :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When talking about a particular food or meal, *eat* and *have* can function interchangeably most of the time. Of the two, *have* is the more versatile and generic word:

Let's start with your last example:

> I'm eating pizza now. Let me call you back – I don't want my pizza getting cold.
>   I'm having pizza now. Let me call you back – I don't want my pizza getting cold.

I see no real difference in those two statements. I think I'd be more likely to use the first, but the second wouldn't jar my native ear.

Then your breakfast example:

> I eat breakfast every day at 8 o'clock.
>   I have breakfast every day at 8 o'clock.

Once again, either one of those is okay, although the second sounds a little bit more formal for some reason. In its seventh definition for *have*, [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/have) mentions:

> **have** (*verb*) [TRANSITIVE] [NEVER PASSIVE] to eat or drink something. This word is often used in polite offers and requests
>
> - *Can I have another piece of that delicious cake?*
> - *Let me buy you a drink. What’ll you have?*
> - *Why don’t you stay and have lunch with
>     us?*
>
> I’ll have (=used for requesting food or drink in a restaurant): *I’ll have the roast beef, please.*

There are a few places where the two words aren't interchangeable. The end of that definition gives one example; if I was ordering at a restaurant, I wouldn't say, "I'll eat the roast beef, please." That might be true, if that's what I'm ordering – but it's simply not idiomatic to say it that way.

Another clue is that *have* is always transitive. So, it's perfectly fine to say:

> I'm starving – let's eat!

but you wouldn't be able to say:

> I'm starving – let's have!

Here's one more odd case:

> I'm hungry; let's have at that hamburger place.
>   I'm hungry; let's eat at that hamburger place.

In this case, we can't use *have* to mean *eat*, because we're not using the word transitively. We can fix that by saying:

> I'm hungry; let's have hamburgers at that place.

However, the first is not necessarily grammatically incorrect, because we could be using the phrasal verb *have at*. NOTE: This would be a **very** informal usage of *have at*, but I give it a mention because it shows how complex and flexible English can be, especially when dealing with informal expressions and eating food. When I was in college, one of my roommates might have said:

> I'm hungry; I think I hear hamburgers calling my name!