# I can't remember the last time that I have had breakfast vs ... had eaten breakfast

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

What is the difference between these expressions:

> I can't remember the last time that I have had breakfast

vs.

> I can't remember the last time that I have eaten breakfast

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See also [Using the verb 'have' instead of the verb 'eat'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49161/using-the-verb-have-instead-of-the-verb-eat).

Comment: I'd prefer past tense "had" or "ate" in either case

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.  "Have" is commonly used as a synonym for "eat".

> We often **have** dinner around 7 in the evening.
>
> The children **have** their lunch around noon.

Note that if the perfect tense is used in a question, the answer is often given in the simple tense to avoid repeating "have".

> A: **Have** the children **had** their lunch yet?
>   B: Yes, they **have**.

Still, the perfect tense ("Yes, they *have had*") is fine.  It's a personal preference.

Comment: @user5577  I'm afraid I don't understand your objection.